# Javascript dates mysteriously change format when I send to client

Tags: javascript, node.js

I receive a date from a database and log them in my server code (Node.js). It's formatted like this:

```
Wed Jul 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Then I do absolutely nothing to it, send to my client, and log what it received:

```
"2023-07-05T05:00:00.000Z"
```

How is this possible? What's happening?

Comment: If you want to send a formatted date string, you should format it yourself *before* sending it to the client, because, as @Barna said in his answer, for JSON it is by default stringified (to an ISO string). Maybe [this module](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler) helps.

Comment: `Wed Jul 05 2023 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` is the default representation of a Date using the `toString()` function. `2023-07-05T05:00:00.000Z` is an ISO-8601 formatted/serialised version for passing between applications.

Comment: What you receive from your database is a `Date` object, not a string. `console.log` uses one string formatting (that depends on your system timezone, btw), sending it to the client uses a different serialisation. Nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript specification says that that's how `Date` should be represented in JSON (it's not specified at all by the JSON spec). See [What is the "right" JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format)

If you want the format you show, convert the `Date` to a string first:

```js
const d = new Date();
console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
console.log(JSON.stringify(String(d)));
```